# How to remove the null value exception in the following statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

The following code is raising null value exception

```
Record rec = (Record)obj.Records.Where(x => x.Id == no).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: To remove the null value exception find the value that is null and make sure it isn't before you run that statement... Its kind of difficult to know what you are asking since we can't tell which of your values are null...

Comment: It is actually the Records rec that is getting null, but am having no idea about it, beacuase everything else is just right.

Comment: @CodeCaster: This is my code if u could help

    int index = GridView1.EditIndex;
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];
    TextBox t1 = row.FindControl("txt_name") as TextBox;
    TextBox t2 = row.FindControl("txt_address") as TextBox;
    Label id = row.FindControl("lbl_Id") as Label;
    int no =Convert.ToInt32(id.Text);
    Record rec = obj.Records.First(x=>x.Id==no);
    rec.Name = t1.Text;
    rec.Address = t2.Text;
    obj.SaveChanges();

Comment: Yes I could most certainly help, but not if you don't show what you have tried. That is how this site works.

Comment: @CodeCaster I am fetching the data from the gridview and it my requirement to reflect that change in the database as well

Comment: I mean showing you understand the problem, did research to find a solution and showing what you have found and tried.

Answer (score 4):

There is three potential places where a `NullReferenceException` could occur (**edit:** we now know `Id` is an `int`):

1. `obj.Records` if `obj` is `null`
2. `Records.Where(...)` if `Records` is  `null`
3. `x.Id` in your lambda if there is a `null` entry in your `obj.Records` enumerable (ie `x` in that context is `null`).

Here are where it wouldn't (assuming it compiles):

1. `SingleOrDefault` will only throw an exception if there is **more than one** entry. If there isn't, it return `null` for a reference type, or the default value for a value type.
2. `(Record)` casting. Since there is no compiler error, I assume `Record` is a class. If there is a value, it would throw an exception only if it's an invalid cast (and not a null exception). A `(Record)null` is perfectly valid for a reference type.

You should debug and step through to find out where it is causing the exception.

Comment: The rec object is showing the null exception..

Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @AshishBabu You mean the line (the code you supplied) does ? If you mean `rec` is `null` it's perfectly normal if the right hand side throw an exception. A reference type will have a default value of `null`. If you are debugging and the exception is thrown at that line, check of `obj`,  `obj.Records` and the items in `obj.Records` for the culprit. If the cause of the exception is `rec` but _after_ this line, you just need an additional logic to handle a possible `null` value for your `rec` variable. It's hard to say. You are only showing us one line.

Answer (score 2):

Well, either `obj.Records` is `null` **or** it doesn't find any records. But this also can't actually work ... `x.Id == no` ... unless of course `no` is a variable somewhere.

Change the line to this:

```
Record rec = obj.Records.Where(x => x.Id == no).SingleOrDefault() as Record;
```

See, the `default` for the type is going to be `null`. Further, it's **really unlikely**, though I don't know your code fully, that the aforementioned line can't simply be:

```
Record rec = obj.Records.Where(x => x.Id == no).SingleOrDefault();
```

Isn't `Records` a listing of the `Record` type?

Comment: why can't `x.ID == no` work?

Comment: @Chris _If_ there is a `null` entry in the `Records` enumerable.

Comment: @Chris, well if `no` is a variable I guess it could. :D

Comment: @TheSolution `no` wouldn't cause a `NullReferenceException`. It's just an equality comparison.

Comment: I assumed `no` was a variable (no can be an abbreviation for number).

Comment: @TheSolution I answered your comment, not your answer

Comment: @SimonBelanger, I'm a little confused I guess, I never commented that `no` would throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @TheSolution "if `no` is a variable I guess it could" (in answer to Chris) implies that the variable `no` would cause a `NullReferenceException`. At least, to me.

Comment: yes no is an integer value.

Comment: @AshishBabu, alright then there's no concern there. `Id` and `no` are `int` so there's no risk for a `NullReferenceException`. Change your line of code to get rid of the unnecessary casting and you're good.

Comment: @The SolutionI have tried it but to of no avail.

Comment: @AshishBabu, is `obj` null by chance?

Comment: @The Solution,, thanks i got my solution. it had some prolem in entity  framework, i made an another entity for it, and then it was working fine.. Thanks all